# Count two columns and show total where criteria met

Tags: mysql

I have seen this question asked and answered here and elsewhere and still cannot get the result I want.  So, please excuse the duplication.

I want to return a table that shows how many times a player (two columns of players) won a game (column named place that has a 1 in it).

My query is:

```
SELECT `player1` as Winner, Count( * ) AS Count
FROM scores
WHERE `place` =1
UNION ALL
SELECT `player2` as Winner, Count( * ) AS Count
FROM scores
WHERE `place` =1
ORDER  BY count DESC
```

The table structure is:

```
player1 varchar
player2 varchar
place   smallint
Other unrelated columns
```

I would like a response that looks like this:

```
Winner     Count
Joe          5
Sam          4
Bill         3
```

The column labels are not critical to me, since I will grab the result and put it on a web page.

phpadmin reports an error in my query, while Instant SQLformatter (http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm?ref=g_wangz) seems to say the query is OK (formats query rather than showing error).

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, who won if the record in `scores` is `('Joe', 'Sam', 1)`?

Comment: What do your columns mean? Is it that if theres a clear winner, player2 is null, and if there's a tie player2 is not null? Or is it that *either* can be null? I've never seen a tar like this - I don't understand at all. Please enlighten me (us)

Comment: The table holds information about duplicate bridge games (wonderful game almost as much fun as programming!).  The game is played by pairs and the table has a column for pairs and then separate columns for each of the players in the pair.  The query will show which individual players had the most wins in all the reported games.  Players play with different partners sometimes.  In my example maybe Joe and Bill had played together 3 times while Sam had played with 4 other people who would be further down the result table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would alter the query slightly to the following. This query converts your `player1` and `player2` columns into a single column with multiple rows, then you can apply the count:

```
select Winner,
  count(*) Total
from
(
  SELECT `player1` as Winner
  FROM scores
  WHERE `place` =1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `player2` as Winner
  FROM scores
  WHERE `place` =1
) src
group by winner
order by total desc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/951ef/3)

Comment: Thanks.  works perfectly (once I included DESC in the order by).

Comment: @Bill Yup, I missed that. :)

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to vote an answer up, but I sure would if I did!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple `UNION ALL` and calculate the result using `GROUP BY` on the player name;

```
SELECT Name AS Winner, COUNT(Name) AS Count
FROM (
  SELECT player1 AS Name FROM Scores WHERE place=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT player2 AS Name FROM Scores WHERE place=1
) a
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

[An SQLFiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d31f6/5).

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to vote an answer up, but I sure would if I did!

Comment: @Bill You can mark your question as answered by checking the transparent checkbox at either answer. If both answers were equally helpful, bluefeet was a few seconds faster, so I'd mark his :)